# Center group of div's that are aligned to bottom

Tags: html, css

I am trying to center a group of divs horizontally inside another div. I would also like those divs to be aligned to the bottom. It seems I can only get one or the other.

Here is a fiddle with what I am getting with the following code: 
https://jsfiddle.net/ezka8Lpw/2/embedded/result/

```
.sandBox{   
    position:relative;
    background-color: #00FF00;
    width: 1440px;
    max-width:100%;
    min-height:560px;
    margin:auto;
    text-align:center;
}
.options{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
}
.option-group{
    width:240px;
    height:75px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left:10px;
    margin-right:10px;
    background-color: #EC3538;
}
.active-option-group{
    text-align:left;
    height: 240px;
}
.active-option-group div{
    padding: 10px;
}
```

How can I center all three divs? If I remove the position and bottom from the options class the center works but they are not aligned to the bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish this pretty easily with flexbox.  Only change to your CSS is in the `.options` container div:

https://jsfiddle.net/ezka8Lpw/5/embedded/result/

```
html, body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
}
.sandBox{   
    position:relative;
    background-color: #00FF00;
    width: 1440px;
    max-width:100%;
    min-height:560px;
    margin:auto;
    text-align:center;
}
.options{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: flex-end;
    width: 100%;
}
.option-group{
    width:240px;
    height:75px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left:10px;
    margin-right:10px;
    background-color: #EC3538;
}
.active-option-group{
    text-align:left;
    height: 240px;
}
.active-option-group div{
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Here's a pretty excellent tutorial on the ins and outs of layout with flexbox:

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

**UPDATE:**

Here's an expanded block of CSS for `.options` that should cover most browsers.  I've used this layout with Safari, Firefox and Chrome but not tested on various versions of IE.  You can read more about IE version support here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn265027%28v=vs.85%29.aspx:

```
.options{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    width: 100%;
    display: -ms-flexbox;      /* TWEENER - IE 10 */
    display: -webkit-flex;     /* NEW - Chrome */
    display: flex;             /* NEW, Spec - Opera 12.1, Firefox 20+ */
    flex-direction: row;
    -webkit-flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    align-items: flex-end;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with flexbox. Is it supported by all browsers?

Comment: Current versions, yes. http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox.  Though you may need to include vendor prefixed CSS to support everything.  https://css-tricks.com/using-flexbox/.  I'll update my answer with an expanded set of rules which should cover most.

Comment: Here's another good read on flexbox if you're interested: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes.